# reverse check back all the dependencies in the arraylist java

Tags: java, dependencies

Suppose I have TASK array list `{A,B,C,D,E,F}` and Dependencies array list indicated each of correspond TASK `{-,-,A,AB,CD,E}`.

I have no problem find the forward dependencies in java program, but what if I would like it reverse and store into the new array backward list such as `{CD,D,E,E,F,-}` ?

Forward:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit unclear to me how your tasks are defined but suppose a task is a class like this:

```
class Task {

    private final String name;

    public Task(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then you could define your input array lists like this (provided that your have imported the asList() and emptyList() methods statically):

```
    final Task a = new Task("A");
    final Task b = new Task("B");
    final Task c = new Task("C");
    final Task d = new Task("D");
    final Task e = new Task("E");
    final Task f = new Task("F");

    List<Task> tasks = asList(a, b, c, d, e, f);

    List<List<Task>> dependencies = asList(
        emptyList(), 
        emptyList(),
        asList(a),
        asList(a, b),
        asList(c, d),
        asList(e)
   );
```

Calculate the forward references could be done in many ways. Here is one example:

```
    public List<List<Task>> forwardDependencies(
        List<Task> tasks,
        List<List<Task>> dependencies
    ) {
    List<List<Task>> forwardDependencies = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Task task : tasks) {
        List<Task> forwardDependency = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < dependencies.size(); i++) {
            List<Task> dependency = dependencies.get(i);
            if (dependency.contains(task)) {
                forwardDependency.add(tasks.get(i));
            }
        }
        forwardDependencies.add(forwardDependency);
    }
    return forwardDependencies;
}
```

calling

```
        System.out.println(forwardDependencies(tasks, dependencies));
```

will produce

```
        [[C, D], [D], [E], [E], [F], []]
```